# how to store data from .write x-ray to mongodb or firebase

Tags: mongodb, firebase, mongoose, screen-scraping, x-ray

i m looking for a way to write the data to firebase or mongodb using mongoose after scraping it using xray.
my code is similar to the exemple below , i just need to insert it to mongoose instead of result.json on localhost.
firebase is also another alternative if there is a way to perform this please

```js
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();

x('https://blog.ycombinator.com/', '.post', [{
  title: 'h1 a',
  link: '.article-title@href'
}])
  .paginate('.nav-previous a@href')
  .limit(3)
  .write('results.json')
```

thank you

Comment: It appears this data is just that; data. It could be treated as an ascii string and written to any database. Can you share what you have tried or what is preventing the data from being written? Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the result passing `object` to the database with mongoose in the callback function

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();

x('https://blog.ycombinator.com/', '.post', [{
  title: 'h1 a',
  link: '.article-title@href'
}])
  .paginate('.nav-previous a@href')
  .limit(3)

  (function(error, object){        // callback
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }else {
    console.log('result is: ')
    console.log(object);           // object is what you want to save
  }
})
```